# PHP form error: PHP file is not fetching data from the contact form

Tags: php, html, smtp

I am encountering an issue in my contact form implementation. Upon user input, the intended behavior should be pushed using 'Method: post' and with the help of the 'mail.php' file. Subsequently, the system is designed to post the data from the contact form. However, this fetching method seems to be causing a runtime error, which I've been unable to identify.

Here is my form :

```
<form action="assets/php/sent-mail.php" method="post" role="form" class="email-form">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col form-group">
      <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name"
        placeholder="Your Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col form-group">
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email"
        placeholder="Your Email" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject"
      placeholder="Subject" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message"
      required></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center"><button type="submit">Send Message</button></div>
</form>
```

and here is my php code :

```
<?php
require_once (__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php');

use SendinBlue\Client\Configuration;
use SendinBlue\Client\Api\TransactionalEmailsApi;
use SendinBlue\Client\Model\SendSmtpEmail;

// Set up configuration
$config = Configuration::getDefaultConfiguration()->setApiKey('api-key', 'xxxxxxxx');

// Create an instance of the TransactionalEmailsApi
$apiInstance = new TransactionalEmailsApi(new GuzzleHttp\Client(), $config);

var_dump($_POST);

if (isset($_POST["name"], $_POST["email"], $_POST["subject"], $_POST["message"])) {
    // Form data
    $u_name = $_POST["name"];
    $u_email = $_POST["email"];
    $u_subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $u_message = $_POST["message"];

    // Build SendSmtpEmail object
    $emailObject = new SendSmtpEmail([
        'to' => [['email' => 'tapadippaul@gmail.com', 'name' => 'Tapadip']],
        'subject' => $u_subject,
        'htmlContent' => $u_message,
        'sender' => ['email' => $u_email, 'name' => $u_name],
    ]);

    try {
        // Send the email using the Sendinblue API
        $result = $apiInstance->sendTransacEmail($emailObject);

        // Redirect to a success page
        header("Location: /sent.html");
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Handle exceptions (you might want to log the error)
        echo 'Message could not be sent. Error: ', $e->getMessage();
    }
} else {
    // Handle the case when form fields are not set
    echo 'Form fields are not set.';
}
```

Outcome:

- array(0) { } Form fields are not set.

Expected Outcome:

- Your message has been sent. Thank you!

Comment: Form looks fine, that should send the data as to be expected. Since $_POST is empty, please check what `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` contains. If that says GET, then you likely have an unintended redirect for some reason.

Comment: The only thing that comes to my mind is some kind of redirect. If your form sends user to /some/address.php but that will redirect (301) him to /some-other/address.php, request will be changed from POST to GET and form data will be lost (same applies to www->non www address and any other redirect, but since you're using relative address in your form action, this should not be a problem)

Comment: To assist you better, could you please provide additional details? Open the webpage, right-click, select "Inspect," navigate to the "Network" tab, ensure "Preserve log" is enabled, then reload the page. Take a screenshot of the network requests, and kindly include it in your question. This will help us analyze the network activity and offer more precise assistance.